# Why network shares enumeration is so slow on Windows?

Tags: winapi, smb

Retrieving a list of network shares via Windows API functions NetShareEnum or WNetEnumResource takes up to 60 (!!!) seconds to complete a reqest. Maybe someone knows why it's SO slow? Maybe it's possible to use some API / library (like SMB) to enum shares at sane speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why it is so slow, if a host is unavailable or not responding for whatever reason (requiring login credentials, for instance), Windows will wait for the timeout limit to be exceeded, for every share known in the network (which can be multiple per host). Windows' default timeouts are insanely long.

Reducing the timeout to something like 50ms (which should never be exceeded in a LAN) might help here, ultimately it depends on the amount of hosts tested.

I cannot help concerning alternatives towards the API, sorry.

Comment: This 60 seconds is for computers that are responding perfectly fine and shows list of shares. What "credentials" problem it can be that triggers timeouts?

Comment: If any share requires login information and Windows doesn't have it saved somewhere, I'm not sure whether it will keep trying to log in anonymously or whether it will simply skip it (which would be the expected behaviour, but Windows' network ways are weird at many places). If your hosts respond perfectly fine, however, I don't think it's any of what I said.

Comment: How do you reduce the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

There is something you might want to try, which is to enumerate the same shares with Linux (you can use a LiveCD). In my test, I've seen that the router also gets asked for possible network shares (my router runs Linux and it was what my ISP gave me, so it might be common).

So, maybe Windows is asking the router for network shares for a long time (which shouldn't happen...) and waiting synchronously for it to respond with shares.

(Who was the genious that designed this API to be synchronous?)